# Are RESTful Web Services considered an example of SOA?

Tags: rest, soa

Does REST constitute a Service Oriented Architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty philosophical and a very general question that is very likely to be removed, I'll share my thoughts though.

There is a concept called Resource Oriented Architectures, defined by Richardson and Ruby in [*RESTful Web Services (O'REILLY 2007)*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do). I think the term is the best one to describe the most common approach to REST.

The main idea of ROA is defined by four concepts:

> 1. Resources
> 2. Their names (URIs)
> 3. Their representations
> 4. The links between them

and four properties:

> 1. Addressability
> 2. Statelessness
> 3. Connectedness
> 4. A uniform interface

When talking about RESTful Web Services, I think it's good to stick to the term ROA and all information it carries.

As for SOA, the name is extremely vague. Some people think it should be reserved for Big (SOAP-based) Web Services only. Personally, I consider ROA a variant of SOA. The authors of the book, hovewer, refuse to make a final statement.

> Service-Oriented Architecture (SOA) is perhaps the least well-defined term of all, which
>   is why I called it out in Chapter 1 as a term I wasn’t going to use. I know of no litmus
>   test which indicates whether a given implementation is SOA or not.
>
> Richardson & Ruby, *RESTful Web Services*, O'REILLY 2007

EDIT

The book quoted here [has been made available under a Creative Commons License and is now possible to download free of charge](http://restfulwebapis.org/rws.html).

Comment: The *RESTful Web Services* was given *Creative Commons license* and is now available for free at http://restfulwebapis.org/rws.html

Comment: @pepr excellent news. Thanks a lot. I'll include this in my answer right away.

Answer (score 3):

SOA and REST are both architectural styles. They have some common architectural styles they draw from (like Client/Server and Layered System) but the also draw from some different styles that aren't shared (e.g. SOA builds on Pipes & Filters and REST on Uniform Interface).

You can build RESTful SOA's but you'd have to adhere to the principles of both to that. 
Also don't confuse REST with just using HTTP technology for implementing SOA.

You can see [this pdf](http://www.manning.com/rotem/SOAp_SampleCh10.pdf) which contains chapter 10 of [my book](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/). Section 10.1 discusses REST & SOA in more detail